# how to use tables in .asm file that are already declared and initialised in .h file

Tags: c, assembly, x86

i declared a table(array) in .h file.

Now i want to use that file in .asm but i am unable to include .h into .asm

Help me out

Comment: What does 'declared and initialised a table' mean?  Like a C array?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a C declaration something like:

```
char array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

You can use it in your assembly file like this:

```
    .globl _array

lea  _array(%rip), %rbx
movb (%rbx), %al
```

The `lea` instruction puts the base address of `array` into `rbx`, and then the `movb` instruction grabs the first byte out.  You could use `1(%rbx)` to get `array[1]`, and so forth.

NB - my example is from a Mac OS X test app I just made.  If you're on a different system, you might have to do something different.